# Why does <input> inside an overflow <div> move itself when typing

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have no idea whats going on here:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 70px; height: 100px; left: 60px; top: 30px; overflow:hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 192, 192);">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 22px; left: 18px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type here" style="width: 150px; height: 21px; overflow: hidden;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MX54/1/

Type in the textbox and it changes its position. No JS involved!
Why is that? Which CSS rule to the rescue?

Edit:
Thanks for clarification. I changed the  width to 100% - good enough:
http://jsfiddle.net/7MX54/2/

Comment: I don't kwow if there is a solution! Why you want your input more large than your div?

Comment: It is a horizontal scroll - a browser behavior..How else would you know what you are typing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a huge column of textboxes and you tab through them, eventually the page will "magically" scroll down so that the textbox you are typing in is in view. This is exactly the same thing. The browser will ensure that you can see where you are typing.

`overflow:hidden` does NOT prohibit scrolling, it merely disables the scrollbar. The scroll position can still be changed by JavaScript, or by the textbox as seen here.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the textbox’s position isn’t changing; its container is scrolling. This is a browser accessibility thing, and CSS can’t do that.

You’ll notice the same thing in any `overflow: hidden;` container when the focus changes to something out of view, for example.

Comment: Ok, so if there are no scrollbars, the browser will scroll anyway. I'm more used to Desktop development, so its a new behaviour to me.

Comment: @user2823670: What did you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your input is it's parent is wider than your wrapper div. Make the width of the outer div to minimum 170px and your problem is gone.

Or make the width of the input small enough that it fits the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the first div width, then you will be able to see the input.
For example: `width: 270px;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarification. I changed the width to 100% - good enough:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type here" style="width: 100%; height: 21px;"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MX54/2/